# Pass value of multiple input fields in jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple input fields, like

```
  <p>Filter by gender</p>
  <select class="filter-users">
     <option value="female">Female</option>
     <option value="male">Male</option>
   </select>
   <p>Filter by city</p>
      <input class="filter-users" type="text" name="city">
```

How to create GET request url with these one or all of these inputs

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/users/filter",
  type: "get", 
  data: { 
    city: city, 
    gender: gender
  },
  success: function(response) {

  }
});
```

How to make ajax request every time on of the filter inputs changed? For example send new request when on option change, or text input was entered? 
So what I am trying to explain is, there is no submit button. Requests needs to be made everytime one of these fields changes

Comment: multiple input forms or multiple input fields?

Comment: I don't get the question, you're already passing in both of your input values

Comment: do you want to get the value from your "ddl", and then pass it?

Comment: @Amit multiple fields

Answer (score 1):

You can use `serializeArray`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/users/filter",
  type: "get", 
  data: $("form").serializeArray(),
  success: function(response) {
  }
});
```

Or you also can use `serialize` in case you don't need JSON but URL-encoded parameters.

Answer (score 0):

for this "How to make ajax request every time on of the filter inputs changed"-

```
$('input.filter-users').on('change', function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "/users/filter",
     type: "get", 
    data: $("form").serializeArray(),
    success: function(response) {
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: @Amit for select use as `$('.filter-users').on('change', function(){`., the above answer for input type field,